# 16-segment display driver ICs

Tags: microcontroller, display

I would like to know what ICs are available to control 16-segment displays.

I have three 1-digit 16-segment displays. I want to control these displays separately by a microcontroller.

It is not practical to connect all pins to a microcontroller. Please give me any suggestions for that.

Comment: Second result on Google for "16 segment display" - MAX6954.

Comment: Yeah that only thing I get from internet

Answer (score 0):

There are so many driver's available in market with almost similar functionality.

Go with some thing like  [HT16K33](http://www.holtek.com/documents/10179/116711/HT16K33v120.pdf) which is an I2C led segment driver, with which I had worked

you can also try this out:
use the host controller as driver by using [multiplexing or Charlieplexing](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Xxx3Sg9Jtqo/UIEZAujZC3I/AAAAAAAAB1c/C88PD-ZMta4/s1600/MuxChax.jpg) technique. Which can save cost, if you are looking for an economical solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think the MAX6954 mentioned in some comments is your best bet. It is a serial-interfaced chip so it only uses 4 pins for communication. It can control up to 8 digits and takes care of multiplexing and BCD decoding so it's relatively easy to use. You will need to learn how to write data to different registers using the serial port to use it.

https://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/en/an/AN3212.pdf

https://forum.arduino.cc/t/max6954-anyone-have-any-luck-with-inferfacing-with-arduino/127063

https://gist.github.com/AnthonyDiGirolamo/1176125